# addEventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function exe()
{
  document.getElementById("cal").addEventListener("click", checkNumber,false);//after the load event,it call this function to register button event
}
function checkNumber()
{enter code here
  var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number"));
  var number2 = document.getElementById("textbox");
  var isPrime = true;

                if (isNaN(number1))
                    number2.value = (number1 + " is not a valid number! Try again!");
                else{
                    if (number1 == 1)
                        number2.value = (number1 + " is not prime!");
                    else{
                        for (var i=2; i<number1; i++){
                            if (number1 % i == 0){
strong text                             number2.value = (number2 + " is not prime. It is divisible by " + i + ".");
                                isPrime = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isPrime)
                            number2.value = (number1 + " is prime!");
                    }

}
window.addEventListener("load",exe,false);//the first load of the page will execute this function and call function exe()
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="form1">
<h1 align="center">prime number calculator</h1><br>
<input align="center" type="text" size="" name="number" id="number"/><br>
<input type="button" name="cal" id="cal" value="Calculate" />
</form>
<section>
<input align="center" type="text" size="" name="num2" id="textbox"/>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I have studied `javascript` before this but the method I use is `onclick or onload`, I've never used addEventListener before, my code didn't function at all. First, when the page loads, I register an event to trigger the other function and register an event for the button, after that I call the other function for further calculation but it wouldn't work at all.  I don't know which lines of codes are inappropriate, this condition must use `addEventListener`.

Comment: why is there "enter code here" in the beginning of the function?

Comment: I assume those `enter code here` and `strong text` are not littered over your actual code?

Comment: please take your time to rewrite your question, so it can be understood

Comment: And what is `<script ="text/javascript">`??

Comment: before posting the question at least you can remove syntactical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code. Here is the corrected version

```
<html>
<head>
<script ="text/javascript">
function exe()
{
  document.getElementById("cal").addEventListener("click", checkNumber,false);//after the load event,it call this function to register button event
}
function checkNumber()
{
  var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
  var number2 = document.getElementById("textbox");
  var isPrime = true;

                if (isNaN(number1))
                    number2.value = (number1 + " is not a valid number! Try again!");
                else{
                    if (number1 == 1)
                        number2.value = (number1 + " is not prime!");
                    else{
                        for (var i=2; i<number1; i++){
                            if (number1 % i == 0){
                                number2.value = (number1 + " is not prime. It is divisible by " + i + ".");
                                isPrime = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isPrime)
                            number2.value = (number1 + " is prime!");
                    }
                }

}
window.addEventListener("load",exe,false);//the first load of the page will execute this function and call function exe()
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="form1">
        <h1 align="center">prime number calculator</h1><br>
        <input align="center" type="text" size="" name="number" id="number"/><br>
        <input type="button" name="cal" id="cal" value="Calculate" />
    </form>
    <section>
        <input align="center" type="text" size="" name="num2" id="textbox"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Can you please accept the answer if it has worked for you. Thanks.